# Pass a variable from a form event listener to the controller?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an event listener associated to a form type, that runs this code:

```
 $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {

            $entity = $event->getData();

            $baseUrl= $options['baseUrl'];

            $fileNameOr="";
            $nombreFicheroInterno = $entity->getFile();

            $file = $entity->getFile();
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $filePars = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileNameOr = $filePars[0];
            $fileExtension = $filePars[1];

            if ($fileExtension == 'CSV' || $fileExtension == 'csv') {
                    $fileExtensionType = 2;
            } else if ($fileExtension == 'TXT' || $fileExtension == 'txt') {
                    $fileExtensionType = 1;
            }
            $separatorType= $entity->getSeparatorType()->getId();
            $numLineasCabecera = $entity->getHeadLinesNumber();
            $algoritmoTecnica = $entity->getAnalysisType()->getId();
            $algoritmoMetodo = $entity->getSubanalysisType()->getMethod();


            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.' . $nombreFicheroInterno->guessExtension();


            $nombreFicheroInterno->move($baseUrl . 'DBSpectra/MuestrasTemp', $filename);


            $res=shell_exec('sh '.$baseUrl.'run_DBSpectralMatching.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/ "'.$baseUrl.'" "'.$fileNameOr.'" "'.$filename.'" "['.$fileExtensionType.' '. $separatorType .' '.$numLineasCabecera.' '.$algoritmoTecnica.' '.$algoritmoMetodo. ' ' . '8888' .']"');

                           $baseUrl . 'DBSpectra/Resultados/' . $compoundId . '-MathDecision.' . $nombreTecnica . '.txt'
             );
```

As you can see, the code is getting the data from the submitted form and executes a Matlab algorithm. Depending on the result of the algorithm (`$res`) the response will be one or other.

How can I pass the variable `$res` of the algorithm to the controller to give one response or another? Or maybe should I place the code inside the eventlistener directly in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Any solution provided will be a workaround. Simply because there is no sigle reason you have to call MatLab from inside the form listener.

Simply validate the form, grab the values you need from inside your controller and then execute MatLab.